# PHP Variable inURL

Tags: php, mysql

I have a display page pulling from a database. With that I have a display function. I have everything working correctly, but I want to change the variable that is visible at the end of the URL, now it is from the 'id' column in my database and I would like it to be from the 'name' column.

This is my display function (included in another file)

```
public function __construct($rid, $table) {
/* Connect to Database */
    require('dbinfo.php');
    //$table=$this->table;  // Choose Table Optional
    $link = mysql_connect($databaseip,$username,$password);
    mysql_select_db($database,$link);
    $query = "SELECT * FROM $table WHERE rid=$rid";
    $result=mysql_query($query);
    $this->result = $result;
    mysql_close($link);
```

And the Get PHP in the header of the display page is as follows:

```
<?php
$rid = $_GET['r'];
require('func/recipe.php');
// Recipe Display Function
if (isset($_GET['r'])) {$recipe = new recipeObject($rid,'my table name');} else {
  header('location: SET URL');
}

?>
```

And my database structure looks like this - https://www.dropbox.com/s/rfga1vl8miqcd9s/database.png?dl=0

Comment: Um... `where name = ?` or whatever the column name is?

Comment: I have done that and nothing changes.

Comment: what `url` you want to put there?

Comment: First of all, you need to go read up on SQL injection. And then secondly, on the difference between numbers and string literals.

Comment: @jacob I do hope your table name does not have spaces, because the way you're using the variable it would throw an error if it does. You could however change it to \`$table\`

Comment: Your code is SQL-injectable. `index.php?r=1+or+1%3D1+INTO+OUTFILE+%27%2Fvar%2Fwww%2Fdump.txt%27+--`

Comment: @FrayneKonok I want to put the variable from the 'name' column there and updating `WHERE name=$rid` doesn't update it.

Comment: Hello,  sql injection... Always escape your input or use prepared statements.

Comment: @Prix no it doesn't, I just dropped that in there for ease.

Comment: *"doesn't update it"* - What do you mean by that? what results are you getting now and if not any, what should it be?

Comment: @jacob, is your `name` contain some spaces, spacial characters???

Comment: Consult these following links http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-error.php and http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php
and apply that to your code, should there be any.

Comment: @FrayneKonok the names in the column do contain spaces on some yes.

Comment: @Fred-ii- by that I mean it does nothing, and pulls no errors.

Comment: are you checking for errors? I included another comment up there ;-)

Comment: so use some `urlencode($userinput)` for encoding.

Comment: if your query requires a db connection, then you need to do this `$result=mysql_query($query, $link);` with a `mysql_error($link)` to it, and we don't know how you're pulling that GET array from, `?r=xxx....` ? Plus, could be a variable scope issue. Again, check for errors with the links I gave you and do a `var_dump();` - Best I can suggest here.

Comment: @Fred-ii- I don't see any errors when I add an echo for errors

Answer (score 0):

So I missed this big time the first time around. My apologies. Here is what I found to work for the query portion. And should help with SQL Injections.

```
$termSafe = mysql_real_escape_string($rid);
$query = "select * FROM $table WHERE (name LIKE '$termSafe')";
```